# Single UIViewController Auto-rotation inside UITabBar

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbar

Hi my `TabBarViewController` Hierarchy is like this. All `ViewControllers` attached with `tabbar` are without `navigationController`.

`UIViewController` (Home View), when Pushed it navigate to `tabBar` based `ViewController` at index 0, User Can come back from `tabBarViewControllers` to home `viewController` at any time using back button in navigation bar.

```
UITabBarViewController (BaseViewController)
    -ViewController0,(NO Navigation ViewController)
    -ViewController1 (NO Navigation ViewController)
    -ViewController2 (NO Navigation ViewController)
    -ViewController3 (NO Navigation ViewController)
    -ViewController4 (NO Navigation ViewController)
```

I used this Approach of `Tabbar` based `ViewController`, because `Tabbar` is not Home `ViewController`.

I want to auto rotate only `ViewController2` in Portrait and Landscape. My Project is only in Portrait Mode.

I tried many thing like [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861272/ios-rotation-using-tabbar-controller-locking-to-portrait), But it not getting.

Comment: Sounds unclear , can you elaborate more?

Comment: @Mr.UB i've updated details

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159444/how-to-get-navigation-based-template-functionality-in-swift-programming/39159793#39159793, let me know if you understand something.

Comment: @Mr.UB i got ur point but of tab bar. how can i make single view controller inside tab bar view auto rotate not other view controller inside app. In mY case there is Home View controller between signup or login and Tab bar vc's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi After lot research What i have found, whether it is **Tabbar** or **UIVicontroller**.

As per my Question, My project is in Portrait Mode and I want only single view Controller Auto rotation.Below are the steps, which helped me.

**1 - In App Delegate.h**

```
@property (assign, nonatomic) BOOL shouldRotate;
```

**2 - In App Delegate.m**

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window  NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) __TVOS_PROHIBITED
{
 _shouldRotate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]boolForKey:@"rotateKey"];
 NSLog(@"Did I get to InterfaceOrientation \n And the Bool is %d",_shouldRotate);

 if (self.shouldRotate == YES){
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
 }else{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }    
 }
```

**3 - Now Which UIViewController, You want Auto rotation**,

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:YES];    
  BOOL rotate = YES;
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:rotate forKey:@"rotateKey"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];    
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return YES;
}
```

**4 -Trick Part is**

If you do all above steps, your view controller will get auto rotated, if u come back from current view controller, which is landscape mode. the previous view controller will get auto rotate in landscape  and it will keep chain.

So, to avoid this,

If you are going from view Controller A to View Controller B. View Controller is auto- rotation, then in View Controller A-

**5 - Use this code -**

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{    
 [super viewDidAppear:YES];

 BOOL rotate = NO;
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setBool:rotate forKey:@"rotateKey"];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize]; 
}
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{    
 return NO;
}

 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
 {
  return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
 }

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#else
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
#endif
{
 dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    // UI Updates

 });
   return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
 }
```

Comment: AsSalamu Alaikum Imran, couldn't help for that video calling issue. I'd found an api named [oovoo SDK](https://developers.oovoo.com). Hope u r in some other task. if u want to go for video call feature in ur apps, use this SDK. It's really simple to implement. Thank you.